# CSS bounce animation not working in FF

Tags: css, animation

I have a simple bounce animation working via webkit, any idea why this animation isn't working in FF?

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);}
} 

@keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {transform: translateY(-6px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-3px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {transform: translateY(-6px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-3px);}
}

element {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation-name: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-name: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out;
    animation-name: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the `animation-name` instead of `animation` for other browsers:

```
div {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
  -ms-animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: bounce 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9LXFn/1/).

Note that if you use `animation-name` you have to set other animation related propeties separately like this:

```
-moz-animation-name: bounce;
-moz-animation-duration:1.7s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```